# How to get the distance between two latitude longitude points in anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I am new to **Anylogic** and I am trying to calculate the distance between two points with given **latitude-longitude** values. I want the distance in miles. I have found a method from the Anylogic website that is below

```
default double getDistance(double startLat,
                           double startLon,
                           double endLat,
                           double endLon)
```

Calculates distance by route between two specified points.
Returns:
the distance between two specified points, measured in meters.

> (source:
>   https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fjavadoc%2Fcom%2Fanylogic%2Fengine%2Fgis%2FIGISRouteProvider.html)

However, when I run this for two set of points with lat-long

```
Point 1:
latitude:41.40174, longitude: -72.0201
Point 2:
latitude:45.332, longitude:-73.2215
```

this gives me a distance of `4.1098062654025815` meters in anylogic; which is wrong.Could you please help me in giving insights what I might be doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**What is wrong**

You are currently using the standard distance function from [Utilities](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fjavadoc%2Fcom%2Fanylogic%2Fengine%2FUtilities.html&cp=3_5_0_107), which is using the inputs as cartesian coordinates and not as geographic latitutude and logitude:

```
public static final double getDistance(double x1,double y1,double x2,double y2)

Returns the distance between two given points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2)
Parameters:x1 - the x coordinate of the first pointy1 - the y coordinate of the first pointx2 - the x coordinate of the second pointy2 - the y coordinate of the second point
Returns:the distance between points
```

**How to fix it**

In order to calculate geographic distances with latitude and longitude, you will have to access the functions that come with the [ShapeGISMap object](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fjavadoc%2Fcom%2Fanylogic%2Fengine%2Fpresentation%2FShapeGISMap.html&cp=3_5_9_39):

```
double  getDistanceByRoute(double latFrom, double lonFrom, double latTo, double lonTo)
Calculates length of route from one point to another.
```

```
double  getDistance(double latFrom, double lonFrom, double latTo, double lonTo)
Returns distance, in meters, between 2 given points
```

You can access them by adding a *GIS Map* from the *SpaceMarkup* palette (the instance here named `map`), and referencing it:

```java
map.getDistanceByRoute(41.40174,-72.0201,45.332,-73.2215);
```

**Additional Hint**

You can always check if you are really using the correct function in your context by using Java auto completion (Type the first part of the function name, then CTRL + Space Bar) and having a look in the JavaDoc that is then showing:

[image: Auto Completion]